# Learning to use Git. Local repository / project file directory

Tags: git, github, repository

I am trying to learn to use Github. I have been uploading using the site directly and all that was fine until I ended up with problems with too many files, too large of a file size etc. So I started to use something called Git Portable. I have set up a new repository, which is on my computer. So I guess a local repository?

So I have this local repository, and in another location the project files. I copied from this project file location to the local repository, so I could then push it to Github.

But I am wondering, do I work from that repository. I mean is that now where I edit the code etc from, so the changes can then be pushed? Or do I still use the original location where the project files are? And, if I don't use the new repository to update the code, how do I then update the code in the repository, do I just copy it over like I did before?

I am really new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

I think from hereon out you want to be making changes to your local repository. Once you have changes you want to move to your GitHub, you have to do just two things. What kind of IDE or text editor do you use to edit and add files in your git repository? It might have a UI that will allow you to do this, if not, you can use git from the command line.

1. You need to commit your changes. A "commit" is essentially a set of a changes. You can associate a commit with a message and this can be really if you are working on a team with multiple developers. Read more about committing here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit
2. You need to push your commits. To push is to update your remote repository (GitHub in your case) with your local commits. Read more about pushing here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: I use VS, I am not sure if that has ability to add from that.